# Is there a proof for this or we should accept that?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Why are two independent parameters **necessary** and **enough** for determining position of a point with respect to a reference point in a plane?

In other words, I want to address a point from another reference point in a plane. How many independent parameters are necessary and enough for that aim? And why?

Comment: If you view the plane as the Cartesian product of two axes, then this ought to be obvious enough: A Cartesian product is a set of ordered pairs, and the two data points correspond to each part of the pair. If you're thinking of the plane as something else, then you'll need to explain.

Comment: Since you talking about 2-dimensional space, you need some basis of the space (which includes 2 elements) to represent each variable in that space as a linear sum of the basis elements.

Comment: Whether it is something to prove, or something to accept as given, depends on how you define a plane. It certainly doesn't follow just from the fact that there's only one line passing through two points, because the latter is true also in space, where two numbers are not sufficient to specify a point.

Comment: You shouldn't say "with respect to a reference point in a plane", as this boils down to telling the distance to the reference point, which requires a single independent parameter, not two.

Comment: @T.Bongers Thanks! I want to address a point from another reference point in a plane. How many independent parameters are necessary and enough for that aim? And why?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks! But there are infinite point (on a circle) in a constant distance from a point.

Comment: @celtschk Thanks! You are right it doesn't follow just that fact. I was mistaken.

Comment: @lucas You talk about how many parameters are necessary and in theory you only need on parameter, since you can identify the line and the plane with a bijection.

Comment: @lucas: anyway your formulation is wrong; all points on the circle are at the same distance and have the same "position wrt the reference" and are equivalent in this respect. You should ask for "the poition of a point in a plane", full stop.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But each coordinate system needs an origin, doesn't it?

Comment: I think you have to be more specific about what you mean. There **are** space filling curves so each point can very well be specified with a single parameter. In addition (I think) one could construct mappings of the plane which require three parameters to identify a point.

Comment: A single point doesn't define a coordinate system. Saying "with respect to a point" is either too few or too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the sufficient condition, you can reason as follows:

- choose three points in the plane forming a non-degenerate triangle and choose two sides;
- for any point, there are two unique lines parallel to the respective sides that pass through it;
- the intersection points of the parallels with the sides can be unambiguously located by means of the ratio of lengths.

Conversely, two ratios define two non-parallel lines, that have a single intersection point.

By this method any point can be unambiguously designated by two real numbers.

Comment: Well! But how about other coordinate systems? Polar, path, etc. For example, in polar coordinate system we determine the position of a point by a distance and an angle.

Comment: @lucas This answers and closes the question "two parameters are enough", constructively.

Comment: My main question was: How many [degrees of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(mechanics)) does a point have in a plane (with proof). But I was afraid that it gets closed because of being off-topic.

Comment: @lucas: why this comment ? My answer is about $DOF\le2$.

Comment: I am not mathematician and I am not familiar with technical definitions. I wanted to ask my question in an on-topic form. But it seems that my question has technically mistakes.

Comment: But the answer is $DOF=2$

Comment: @lucas, hem $DOF=2\implies DOF\le 2$, doesn't it ?

Comment: But $DOF\le 2$ means that $DOF$ can be $1$ or $0$ also.

Comment: $2$ independent parameters are **necessary** and **enough**.

Comment: @lucas: for the last time, isn't it clear that my answer is about the "sufficient" requirement ($DOF\le2$), not about the "necessary" one ($DOF\ge2$) ?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get your meaning. But I am sure that the problem is from me not your answer. Thank you very much because of your time and attention.

Comment: @lucas: you shouldn't accept my answer as it's only partial.